# Delete polymorphic relation table automatically

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, eloquent

i have comments table that can have 2 kinds of author, the registered one and the guest.

to handle that, i made polymorphic relation between comments,  user_registered, and guest table

when i delete spesific post in posts table, the comments who have foreign key is also deleted but the problem is the guest and user_registered table that have polymorphic relation to comments table not automatically deleted.

so my question is, can the polymorphic relation table deleted automatically when the main table deleted.
its like the foreign key behaviour (delete cascade)

thx guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [model events](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events) to process relationships upon certain events such as deleting.

Comment: the model events works well, but there is another problem, when comments deleted by foreign key, the model events not work. How i can handle that situation?